# Curly brackets for function blocks in one line functions

Tags: javascript

I am returning to writing javascript after not having used the language for a few years.

It used to be that using inline functions like this

```
doSomething(function() console.log('its done'));
```

would work in all important browsers. Now it seems that chrome is having trouble with this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

But not with this:

```
doSomething(function() {console.log('its done')});
```

What is the reason for chromes strictness? Where can I read about this? Does it make sense and finally how can I turn it off? I prefer the non-curly-brackety version for simple one liners.

Comment: This is non-standard. You should always add the braces. In ES6 you can use short arrow functions, `doSomething(() => console.log('its done'))`

Comment: Why you need so strange syntax? Is it really important for you to save just 2 characters on curly brackets?

Comment: I write a lot of very short functions and having to parse an extra set of brackets is exhausting for my eyes. Extra new lines help but then my code becomes unecessarily long. I like my code short. I'll live either way. Just not as good.